# SQL query to check based on if exists condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a help on sql query where I want to fetch the data if the condition exists or not.

```
select employee.*, stream.*, priority.*
from employee emp,
     stream st,
     priority pr
where emp.st.id = st.id
  and str.pr.id = pr.id
```

So here priority is not mandatory. A value may or may not exists. So If priority does not exist the data should be fetched for emp.st.id = st.id. If it exists then ofcourse emp.pr.id  = pr.id should be included.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and **easier to convert to outer join if needed**!

Comment: Can you please provide some example

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: I have multiple tables connected to each other. So in that here stream and employee are connected and stream - priority are connected. In this case how can i derive a condition

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images) [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have & said:

> ```
> select employee.*, stream.*, priority.*
> from employee emp,
>      stream st,
>      priority pr                     --> priority is not mandatory
> where emp.st.id = st.id
>   and str.pr.id = pr.id
> ```

*Translated* to from English to SQL, it reads as "outer join" which means that something like this might do what you want:

```
select e.*, 
       s.*
       p.*
from employee e join stream s   on s.id = e.st_id
           left join priority p on p.id = s.pr_id         --> this
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope following suggestion will help you,

```
select employee.*, stream.*, priority.*
from employee emp,
     stream st,
     priority pr
where emp.st.id = st.id
  and str.pr.id = pr.id(+)
```

for more details about left/right outer join, you can check below link.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#SQLRF52331